# SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I’ve problem with database on sql server 2008 R2 SP3 (10.50.6560.0).

After I run query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM sys.assemblies
```

I’ve this error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Msg 0,
>   Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Sql server log:

```
BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *   08/10/18 11:59:20 spid 52

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *   Exception Address = 00EDC8D7 Module(sqlservr+0054C8D7)

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *   Access Violation occurred reading address 0000001E

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      * Input Buffer 94 bytes -

2018-08-10 11:59:20.67 spid52      *             SELECT       *  FROM sys.assemblies
```

After I use WinDbg with dumped file. In WinDbg after load file i used this command

```
Ecxr
```

And the result of this command:

> eax=00000000 ebx=059da1e0 ecx=835e1330 edx=00000006 esi=00000000
>   edi=00000000 eip=00edc8d7 esp=059d9eec ebp=059d9f44 iopl=0         nv
>   up ei pl zr na pe nc cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053 
>   gs=002b             efl=00010246
>   sqlservr!AccBindings::ProcessBindingsFirstPass+0x6c6: 00edc8d7
>   0fb74e1e        movzx   ecx,word ptr [esi+1Eh]   ds:002b:0000001e=????

Error exists only on one database, other databases on this server works. I want to migrate this database on Server 2012 but can't restore this database on SQL Server 2012.

Can someone bring me a solution for this problem?

Edit: 
@sp_BlitzErik

After run DBCC checkdb:

```
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'CTK14'.
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Edit for: 
Sean Gallardy

```
0:000> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0ae6baf8 75f22329 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
01 0ae6bb6c 75f22282 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for sqlservr.exe
02 0ae6bb80 02a3b141 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
03 0ae6bc08 02a3ad0a sqlservr!CDmpDump::DumpInternal+0x32e
04 0ae6bc44 024a913e sqlservr!CDmpDump::Dump+0x59
05 0ae6bc80 024a98a5 sqlservr!SQLDumperLibraryInvoke+0x169
06 0ae6bd74 0249e2e4 sqlservr!CImageHelper::DoMiniDump+0x2b0
07 0ae6c314 0249dc94 sqlservr!ContextDumpNoStackOverflow+0x315
08 0ae6cbac 0249d3b1 sqlservr!ContextDump+0x699
09 0ae6cbe8 01837503 sqlservr!stackTraceExceptionFilter+0x1c1
0a 0ae6cbfc 027c02d9 sqlservr!SqlDumpExceptionHandler+0x14
0b 0ae6ce58 027c3066 sqlservr!SOS_OS::ExecuteDumpExceptionHandlerRoutine+0x24
0c 0ae6ce68 027c330f sqlservr!IsNXException+0x1ee
0d 0ae6ce84 70698c0e sqlservr!ex_trans_cexcept+0x4f
0e 0ae6ced0 70698576 msvcr80!_CallSETranslator+0xa3 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\i386\trnsctrl.cpp @ 701] 
0f 0ae6cf04 7069894b msvcr80!FindHandlerForForeignException+0x58 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\frame.cpp @ 934] 
10 0ae6cf64 70698a57 msvcr80!FindHandler+0x33b [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\frame.cpp @ 866] 
11 0ae6cf98 70698b11 msvcr80!__InternalCxxFrameHandler+0xd9 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\frame.cpp @ 524] 
12 0ae6cfd4 7736ab92 msvcr80!__CxxFrameHandler3+0x26 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\prebuild\eh\i386\trnsctrl.cpp @ 311] 
13 0ae6cff8 7736ab64 ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
14 0ae6d0c0 77351a26 ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
15 0ae6d0c0 02544b3a ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x26
16 0ae6d444 02544c61 sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::ValidateSingleColumnAttribute+0x1ef
17 0ae6d4e4 025431e7 sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::ValidateAllColumnAttributes+0xa0
18 0ae6d514 025428b5 sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::CreateRowsetMetadata+0xe7
19 0ae6d5a8 02542eee sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::CreateIndexMetadata+0x1d2
1a 0ae6d5f4 02542c10 sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::CreateObjectMetadataInternal+0x1ce
1b 0ae6d67c 025422f9 sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::CreateObjectMetadata+0x161
1c 0ae6db98 0252c79e sqlservr!CheckMetadataFactory::GetMetadata+0x3c2
1d 0ae6dbc0 0255ba05 sqlservr!CheckBatchGenerator::GetNextBatch+0x165
1e 0ae6dd88 02539c44 sqlservr!CheckTables::BuildAndCheckObjectList+0x390
1f 0ae6ecf4 02538a0e sqlservr!UtilDbccCheckDatabase+0xe32
20 0ae6ed3c 0256383e sqlservr!DbccCheckDB+0x1e6
21 0ae6eda8 01d3a568 sqlservr!DbccCommand::Execute+0xa8
22 0ae6f06c 01033294 sqlservr!CStmtDbcc::XretExecute+0x6d9
23 0ae6f084 012d4d60 sqlservr!CExecuteStatement::XretExecute+0x1b
24 0ae6f130 012d7968 sqlservr!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,1>+0x30e
25 0ae6f21c 012d72df sqlservr!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute+0x748
26 0ae6f2d8 012d8972 sqlservr!CSQLSource::Execute+0x6d8
27 0ae6f468 012d1b24 sqlservr!process_request+0x30d
28 0ae6f5c8 013205e1 sqlservr!process_commands+0x317
29 0ae6f630 013206df sqlservr!SOS_Task::Param::Execute+0x10c
2a 0ae6f664 013203c8 sqlservr!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask+0x83
2b 0ae6f6ac 00e73985 sqlservr!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks+0x132
2c 0ae6f730 00e73870 sqlservr!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint+0x2b5
2d 0ae6f748 00e73096 sqlservr!SystemThread::RunWorker+0x85
2e 0ae6f7b8 00e74e80 sqlservr!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker+0x306
2f 0ae6f82c 706729bb sqlservr!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint+0x142
30 0ae6f864 70672a47 msvcr80!_callthreadstartex+0x1b [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 348] 
31 0ae6f86c 73ea8674 msvcr80!_threadstartex+0x66 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\threadex.c @ 326] 
32 0ae6f880 77345d87 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
33 0ae6f8c8 77345d57 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
34 0ae6f8d8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

@sp_BlitzErik from the checked list in link:

1. OK
2. select * from msdb.dbo.suspect_pages - empty
3. SAN - not applicable
4. OK
5. History - unknown
6. exec sp_BlitzIndex @GetAllDatabases =1; - dosn't return any database (next commands not tested)
7. T1 - doesn't help, T2 - not for now, T3 - the same as on original server, T4 - don't have a earlier backup, T5 - as for now this forum
8. OK
9. Never :)

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to fix this error. It smells like a corrupt database to me. Please run DBCC CHECKDB. [What to Do When DBCC CHECKDB Reports Corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/).

Comment: You have a corrupt database. Please read the link I posted in the first comment.

Comment: What's the stack output? If you open it up in WinDBG use 'k' to show the stack of the asserting thread.